# How many pairs of two distinct integers chosen from the set {1, 2, 3, ..., 101} have a sum that is even?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**My Attempt:**

```
N(even numbers between 1-101) = 50
N(odd numbers between 1-101) = 51
Since pair of two distinct integers that have a sum that is even can only be 
1. odd + odd
2. even + even

Thus, the answer is 51C2 + 50C2 = 2,500
```

Is my answer correct? If yes, how can I verify it?

Comment: You might become a creative mathematician...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  Good work.

To verify the answer, use the same method to solve a similar problem that you can check by hand.  For example:

> How many pairs of two distinct integers chosen from the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ have a sum that is even?

Your same method says that the answer should be ${}_2C_2 + {}_1C_2 = 1$, and it is obvious that there is only one such pair, namely $1, 3$.

If the ${}_1C_2$ disturbs you, use $\{1,2,3,4\}$ instead or $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$; it still checks.

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Total number of sums is $101\choose2$=5050.  Subtract all ODD + EVEN combos: $50\times 51=2550$ confirms your answer of 2500

Comment: Oh you're right, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct and have given a fine justification for your answer.  What more verification do you want?  You could write a small program and count them as an independent check.